# Starting the service in android without user interaction

Tags: android, android-service, android-source

I want to create a service that will analyse the wifi data captured from wlan interface and send it to the server. So I want this service to be stared when the device is connected to an access point.Should I add this in system server. if so how to start that service without any api call or user interaction.

Comment: Does your app consist an `Activity` or not ?

Comment: You can use background services or broadcast receivers for this purpose.

Comment: @ADM No. I want to make that as a System service like Battery Service it(It gives the notification when battery is low). Should I add it in the source code itself and then build and boot?